# Various encryption results using a public key in Android and OpenSSL

Tags: android, openssl, bouncycastle

I am encrypting a string in Android using a public key like this:

```
public static String encryptDataWithPEM(String data, String publicKeyPEM) {
        try {
            PublicKey publicKey = getPublicKeyFromPEM(publicKeyPEM);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
            byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedData);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
private static PublicKey getPublicKeyFromPEM(String publicKeyPEM) {


        try {
            PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new StringReader(publicKeyPEM));
            JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter();
            Object pemObject = pemParser.readObject();

            if (pemObject != null) {
                return converter.getPublicKey((org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo) pemObject);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid PEM format: RSA public key expected");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Repeating encryption in Debian console
`echo -n "Your data to encrypt" | openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey public_key.pem | base64`

But why are the encryption results in Android and in openSSL (Ubuntu) different?

Comment: You mean why do they encrypt to different strings?  Different nonces most likely.  You do NOT want the same values to always encrypt to the same results, that's a weakness in your algorithm that can be exploited to crack the encryption.

Comment: @GabeSechan thank you! I definitely need to learn more about encryption

Comment: For an example of how the same value encrypting to the same value is dangerous-  let's say encrypting the string "hello" always results in "whfit".  And let's say I know the algorithm works on 5 character blocks.  I could encrypt every 5 character string, store the results in a table (called a rainbow table).  I could then decrypt anything sent to you, because I know the total mapping for your key.